# How to add a class for NotesHttpRequest in a notes agent?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I would like to make a simple Notes HTTP Request over a Notes agent, but there is always the following message:

> Class or type name not found: NOTESHTTPREQUEST

**My Code:**

```
Dim webRequest as NotesHTTPRequest
Set webRequest = NotesSession.CreateHTTPRequest()
Call webRequest.get(URL$)
```

**Question:**

What do I have to do, to import the required class for a simple GET Request over Lotus Script in a notes agent?

Comment: NotesHTTPRequest is new with Notes/Domino 10.x. Are you using Notes 10.x?

Comment: Of course not :( why are such simple things in general, specially in Notes always so difficult and complex?! Thank you @PerHenrikLausten for the hint.

Comment: If you're running on Windows, WinHTTP is available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703996/consume-rest-service-in-server-based-agent

Comment: Another alternative is to write your code in Java instead of LotusScript. Notes/Domino agents can be Java, and Java includes the HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection classes that allow reading from URLs. It's also possible to make LotusScript code call Java code via LS2J, which can be useful if you already have LS code that needs changes to read URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NotesHTTPRequest](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_NOTES_HTTPREQUEST_CLASS.html) is new with Notes/Domino 10.x. So you need to use Notes/Domino 10.x to use it.